# moverse a una carpeta con nombre '-' con cd en linux

Tags: bash

Quisiera moverme por bash a una carpeta con nombre '-' o '/home/usuario/-/' pero cd no me funciona entonces alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: ¿Que tal añades una barra invertida antes del `-`?

Comment: ¿Y qué *sugerencias* te muestra `bash`? (al presionar dos veces la tecla `tab`)

Comment: @MauricioContreras Sorprendentemente, cuando activas el auto completador, te da la respuesta equivocada, es decir, el nombre "-" a secas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mi funciona de este modo. Si por ejemplo creo un archivo `script.sh` con este contenido:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/usuario/-
pwd
```

o bien, si ya estoy en la carpeta /home/usuario

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ./-
pwd
```

La barra final es opcional. El comando `pwd` es solo para que te muestre la ruta donde está.

Ten en cuenta que cuando ejecutas el script con `bash script.sh` estás ejecutándolo en un nuevo *proceso de shell*, por lo tanto al terminar seguirás en el mismo directorio donde estabas. Si lo ejecutas con `source script.sh` entonces los comandos se ejecutaran en la *shell actual* y podrás cambiar de directorio si así lo has programado en el `script.sh` y es lo que pretendes.

En bash `cd -` implica un cambio de directorio hacia el immediatamente anterior tal como indica su [página `man`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cd.1p.html):

> When a `<hyphen-minus>` is used as the operand, this shall be equivalent
> to the command:
>
> cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd
>
> which changes to the previous working directory and then writes its
> name.

donde **$OLDPWD** es una *variable de entorno* establecida al valor del anterior *directorio de trabajo*, tal como aparece en la descripción de la misma página `man`.

> If, during the execution of the above steps, the PWD environment
> variable is set, the OLDPWD environment variable shall also be set to
> the value of the old working directory (that is the current working
> directory immediately prior to the call to cd).

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta